# TextBoxFor show date without time

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, html.textboxfor

I want to show date in text field in format **MM/dd/yy**. I described model class as:

```
public class VacancyFormViewModel
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy}")]
    public DateTime SurgeryDate { get; set; }
```

Of course, I can use `EditorFor` instead of `TextBoxFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.SurgeryDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Problem is css styles, customer wants apply bootstrap styles, which are broken:

[image]

if I set `TextBoxFor` instead of `EditorFor` I get the date with time:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.SurgeryDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

[image]

Any way to solve my problem? Or apply styles for `EditorFor`, or show `TextBoxFor` without time, or third way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify date format in `TextBoxFor` helper like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SurgeryDate, "{0:MM/dd/yy}",  new { @class = "form-control" })
```