# Displaying date only in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, date, razor, bootstrap-modal

I'm stuck on this problem, and I don't know why my code does not seem to work. I want to display date only the date I fetch from my SQL Server database in an ASP.NET MVC view, but it seems nothing to work with..

Here is my code

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Separated Date</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SeparatedDate, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
</div>
```

I used a viewmodel where in there I set that it only displays date only.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> SeparatedDate { get; set; }
```

But as I render the page, it still have a time displayed on it

[image: Image when I render the View]

I hope someone can help about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify date format in `TextBoxFor` helper without time part:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SeparatedDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
```

Of course because you're defining `DisplayFormat` with `DataFormatString`, you can use `EditorFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SeparatedDate)
```

Reference: [TextBoxFor show date without time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355155/textboxfor-show-date-without-time)

**Note:** Disabled input helper will not send the value contained inside it. If you want to send it together but still disallowing user input, use `readonly="readonly"` attribute instead.

Comment: thanks man it works, but i have some questions, Why if used TextBoxFor it doesnt work? while in EditorFor it does ???

Comment: `TextBoxFor` requires specified format string to make date formatting works in edit mode, while `EditorFor` automatically formats `DateTime` property bound to it according to `ApplyFormatInEditMode` & `DataFormatString` settings.